# Two wired computers on the router

Tags: router, internet, wired-networking, internet-speed, wired

My husband and I both have gaming computers hard wired into the same router. His computer is significantly faster than mine in terms of downloading and browsing. My computer is newer than his -- freshly built a few months ago. Neither of us are running wirelessly, both plugged in via ethernet cable.

We have tried swapping cables & ports and came to no conclusion. My computer is managing roughly half the speed his is. Router has updated firmware (As of this post), both computers are connected via the same brand of cable (Not that it matters too much) and both are similar in specs however mine is newer and slightly better.

I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting this. Any help?

Edit: I wouldn't doubt my computer is sexist! So, I know my computer is downloading slower because my husband and I both speedtested the connection -- His was significantly higher than mine. Also, if we download games via Steam, we will be on the same server, and his will download much faster than mine. So, speedtest.net & Steam downloads both finish faster on his computer than on mine. I am not sure how to check my link speed -- Could somebody give me a condensed version? After poking through my control panel I found my network card is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller -- if that helps.

Comment: The network card  is the next variable.

Comment: This is because electronic devices (mainly routers) are particularly sexist. hehe, all hilarious puns aside: How do you know his is downloading faster than yours. What stats or info are you looking at to tell you this?

Comment: How are you measuring the speed exactly?

Comment: check your link speed and duplex, to make sure you are at the correct speed, full duplex. sometimes autodetect features don't work with a given NIC/switch combination. make sure you have up to date NIC and chipset drivers. if all else fails, you may need an add in nic. get one with the fastest bus type your system supports (pcie?)

Comment: If nothing still works, can you try switching network cards, like Ignacio mentioned above?

Comment: I would get a large file (250mb+...bigger the better) and send the file to the other computer or anywhere on the internet. When its transferring I would open Start Manager and watch the Network monitor. If it max's out for a few seconds and then drops to nothing for a few seconds (over and over) its your link speed - duplex as @Frank mentions.

Comment: If it is my link speed and duplex, how do I correct this issue? I will attempt to send a file when I find one of appropriate size.

Comment: Zip up a bunch of files or Download an OS ISO file, example ubuntu iso is 700mb (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). If it alternates between MAX & MIN every couple seconds its probably because its half-duplex. Which can be caused by a couple things: Drivers, Bad Cables and/or plugs/jacks...